# Why I get Access denied when try to read file from ProgramFiles/MyApp?

Tags: .net, windows, uac, access-denied

I am trying to read from a config file in ProgramFiles/MyApp but in Windows 7 it throws an exception for Access denied, it is the same and for a file in ProgrammData/MyApp:

fileStream = new FileStream(this.StorageName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Is not it allowed to read only from these folders?

Comment: Need more information:  How did to create the directory and put your file in there?  Are the directory and file owners and permissions set correctly?  Is your stuff in the correct Program Files directory (e.g., Program Files (x86) for 32-bit programs on a 64-bit OS)?

Comment: Both directories are created at the installaction process. The program is x86 so it is installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram, the Windows 7 is x64. I found that it reads without problem when the application is signed, or after UAC question when it is not signed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/53660459-EC32-4819-9213-5190F5A1B885

it seems to be an UAC issue, and you should relocate your information according to nmahajan.

This one is even better:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/dd28741a-1025-4ca2-a88b-95a5ea156e7f

Quoting GTVic:

> 1 - C:\Users\username\Documents
>   2 - C:\Users\username\AppData\Local
>   3 - C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming
>   4 - C:\Users\Public\Documents
>   5 - C:\ProgramData
>   Use for:
>   1 - data private to one user while logged onto one specific computer
>   the database files can be easily found by the user by browsing their Documents folder
>
> 2 - data private to one user while logged onto one specific computer
>   the database files are in a hidden folder but may be accessible by a skilled user
>
> 3 - data private to one user while logged onto any networked computer
>   the database files are in a hidden folder but may be accessible by a skilled user
>
> 4 - data public to any user logged onto a specific computer
>   the database files can be easily found by the user by browsing the public Documents folder
>
> 5 - data public to any user logged onto a specific computer
>   the database files are in a hidden folder but may be accessible by a skilled user

Comment: There's no reason why read-only,program-specific configuration information cannot reside in the Program Files directory with the program itself.